# Based on research, is it better to learn a new language in your mother tongue?

Tags: reference-request, multiple-languages, teaching-methods

I live in a multilingual country and often people that visit a language course will have the class in one of the languages spoken here, let's say French.
But most of these people do not speak a lot of French and there are a lot of problems that arise because some sound does not exist in their mother tongue or the grammar is just different and those problems do not exist in French.

Do you know if there has been any research about learning a language in a course adapted to your mother tongue vs. in a secondary language?

Comment: Could you clarify which of the two following types of situations you want to compare with learning a language in the target language? (a) Learning a foreign language (the target language, e.g. French) in another foreign that is spoken in a multilingual country? or (b) Learning a foreign language in one's native tongue?

Comment: I want to compare (taking English as an example, German being my mothertongue): 
a) learning English in a course where the course is explained in French by a French tutor which is a secondary language for me

with

b) learning English in a class where the tutor speaks German which is my mother tongue